# Add query parameters in link react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to add query parameters in my url, but having trouble. For visual sakes I put the Link object in the onSubmit, but I know that this is not allowed.

```
<form onSubmit={<Link to={{ pathname: '/me', query: { showAge: true } }}/>}>
 .....
</form>
```

Comment: whats the issue you are facing when using the same link line ??

Comment: It says `Expected onSubmit listener to be a function, instead got type object`

Comment: you want to hit this link onSubmit ??

Comment: when I submit the form, I want it to go to `/me` but also have the parameter showAge, so `/me?showAge=true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `browserHistory/hashHistoryWrite.push()`, to got to specific route, `onSubmit` call. Put all the values in query that you want to pass, like this:

```
onSubmit={()=>hashHistory.push({
                 pathname: '/me',
                 query: {a: "a", b: "b", "c": c}
              })
};
```

or

```
onSubmit={()=>browserHistory.push({
                 pathname: '/me',
                 query: {a: "a", b: "b", "c": c}
              })
};
```

Comment: Hm, usually when you add parameters to url there wouldn't typically be `me/params` instead it would be `me?params`

Comment: Yeah, I want to pass multiple parameters, but there is not query parameter in the `browserHistory.push`

Comment: check the updated ans, i thought you just want to pass only one query parameter, in case of multiple use the pathname and query to pass multiple values :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by doing:

```
let clientId = 2;

this.props.history.push({
    pathname: '/client',
    search: "?" + new URLSearchParams({clientId: clientId}).toString()
})
```

or

```
this.props.history.push('/client?clientId=1')
```

I put the above code in a function and binded it in constructor so it has access to `props` and `props.history` in your case:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.onSubmitClick = this.onSubmitClick.bind(this)
}

onSubmitClick(){
    this.props.history.push('/client?clientId=1')
}
```

and

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmitClick}>

</form>
```

You might also need to wrap your component in a `withRouter` decorator eg. `export default withRouter(Component);`